# Extjs 3.4 Ext.tree.TreePanel with TreeLoader

Tags: extjs, extjs3, treepanel

can you help with this code. Why is it that its not loading the data that i want. I manage to add the children without using this process but i want to know how to do this. Well this is better anyways thats why i want this.

```
db_switcher.app.tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
                renderTo: 'treePanel',
                useArrows: true,
                autoScroll: true,
                animate: true,
                enableDD: true,
                containerScroll: true,
                border: false,
                width: 300,
                // auto create TreeLoader
                //dataUrl: 'get-nodes.php',


                //root: {
                //  nodeType: 'async',
                //  text: 'Database',
                //  draggable: true,
                //  id: 'source',
                //  children: []
                //}

                loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
                    dataUrl:  'db_switcher/data'
                    //requestMethod: 'POST'
                    //listeners: {
                    //  beforeload: function() {
                    //  this.baseParams.subFolderID = clickedVal;
                    //      }
                    //}
                }),
                root: new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
                    expand: true,
                    text: "/",
                    id: "/"
                }),
            });

            db_switcher.app.tree.getRootNode().expand();
```

This is the exact data form:

```
[{"db_id":1,"db_host":"xx.xxx.x.xxx","db_name":"service_management","db_user":"xxx","db_driver":"mysql "},{"db_id":2,"db_host":"xx.xxx.x.xxx","db_name":"support_tool","db_user":"xxx","db_driver":"pgsql "}]
```

I hope someone can help me here.

Comment: edited data:

[
  {
     "id":1,
     "text":"xx.xxx.x.xx (service_management)","leaf":true
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "text":"xx.xxx.x.xx(support_tool)",
     "leaf":true
  }
]

Comment: There is no autoLoad for loader, so you have to `db_switcher.app.tree.getLoader().load()` it.

Comment: The following line only produces this error "TypeError: b is undefined" @Michel

Comment: You should build a test case in fiddle, it would be easier to test it.

Answer (score 0):

It is kind of late for some answer, but I had the very same problem and it seems rendering doesn't work properly when leaf attribute is missing in json.

Here goes a working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1s5k&view/editor